# Загрузка файлов по FTP на Windows сервер

Tags: ftp, ajax, php

Как реализовать загрузку файлов по FTP на сервер, под управлением Windows?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=ftp

```
// установка соединения
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

    // вход с именем пользователя и паролем
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    // проверка соединения
    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
            echo "Не удалось установить соединение с FTP сервером!";
            echo "Попытка подключения к серверу $ftp_server под именем $ftp_user_name!";
            exit; 
        } else {
            echo "Установлено соединение с FTP сервером $ftp_server под именем $ftp_user_name";
        }

    // закачивание файла
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);

    // проверка результата
    if (!$upload) { 
            echo "Не удалось закачать файл!";
        } else {
            echo "Файл $source_file закачен на $ftp_server под именем $destination_file";
        }

    // закрытие соединения
    ftp_close($conn_id);
```